# Residue class ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$/I and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$/J

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, factoring, residue-calculus

$I = \left\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix^i : n \in \mathbb{N}, a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\rbrace$

beeing an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with polynomials without a constant term and

$J = \left\lbrace \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ix^i : n \in \mathbb{N}, a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{Z}, a_0 \in 2\mathbb{Z} \right\rbrace$

beeing an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with polynomials with an even constant term. How can I describe the residue class rings of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$/I and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$/J? I have no idea how I should start calculating these. Also I have to find an ideal L in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$/L contains 4 elements.

Is polynomial division the way to go here or is it possible to see the residue class rings in the sets I and J?

Comment: with => without ? If yes, in particular, $x \in I$ and I'm sure you can describe easily $\mathbb Z[x]/I$.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z[x]/I$ the set of polynomials with a constant term? I'm very confused by this right now and I'm not sure whether I'm on the right track.

Comment: Well no, it is not the set of polynomials with a constant term. When I'm trying I can't seem to find any regular residues. It looks like it is  $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: Yes ! In particular, $x \in I$ and then $[p(x)] = [p(0)]$ mod $I$. (Just kill all the $x$-term).

Comment: So $\mathbb Z[x]/I = Z[x]$? But when I'm looking at $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J$ I also can't seem to find any regular residues. It also looks like it is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/J = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ again.

Comment: No, $\mathbb Z[x]/I \cong \mathbb Z$. Because every polynomial is in the same class as a constant term.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\phi, \psi$ with your ring as domain and $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/2$ as codomains as folows:

$\phi(f) = f(0)$

$\psi(f)= f(0)\pmod 2$

Verify that both of them are surjective homomorphisms, and apply fundamental theorem about ring homomorphisms